# Birth of shree raam

Tags: ramayana, rama, ramcharitmanas

We all know the tithi of his birth, but on which weekday was he born?

The tithi is mentioned in both the ramayan but I can't find mention of weekday

Comment: Some people say it's Sunday. But, as far as I recall, there are no such references to the weekday of any incarnation's "birthday", at least not for Sri Rama. Not there in Valmiki Ramayana, not in the Padma, Skanda Purana, Not in Anada Ramayana, They only mention the tithi, nakshatra and time,  not the weekday.